# Text to Speech on Android 4.1.1 Tablet

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I am new to this site but have been a developer for a number of years (Delphi,PHP,Lazarus).  A year ago I started developing in Android(Java - Eclipse) and have recently come across a knotty little problem.

I have developed an app which uses the Text to Speech engine. It works fine on my HTC Sensation, my wife's HTC Desire X and fine on the two Tablet Emulators that I have tested it on in Eclipse/AVD Manager.

I recently installed it on my Father in Laws Lenovo IdeaPad (Android 4.1.1) and it failed.  I use the standard(ish) check for an installed TTS engine and auto-installer if it doesn't find one.  On the IdeaPad, it fails to find the installed(I've checked, it is there) English TTS and instead, launches an installer with the option to install either French, German, Spanish or Italian TTS Engines.  This would suggest to me that it is in some way seeing the english version but not using it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I have posted the relevant sections of code below.

Kind Regards
Gary

```
private TextToSpeech mTts;
private static final int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE = 1234;
```

more of my app code here

```
Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
startActivityForResult(checkIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);
```

more of my app code here

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE)
    {
        if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS)
        {
        mTts = new TextToSpeech(this, null, Str);
        }
        else
        {
            Intent installIntent = new Intent();
            installIntent.setAction(
                    TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
            startActivity(installIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a bug with TTS resource checking in Android 4.1. This is reported as [issue 36430](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=36430)

My experience was that TTS stopped working on a Samsung S3 after upgrading from Android 4.0 to 4.1. The report cited above gives a hint for a workaround, but I did not yet check the workaround.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for that guys. This has had me stumped for 2 days!! I presume then that they fixed it in 4.2 which is why it works ok on my emulator then?  I'll try the isLanguageAvailable and see what I can do.  Thanks again.

Comment: According to the issue tracker it is not yet fixed.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, I love Android as an OS(Linux Geek) and to develop for, but their slow cycle time for fixes and updates is awful!!